Move Default Data Directory of PostgreSQL to a network folder
I am using Windows, and have only 1 C drive.
Currently, my postgreSQL data is located at C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data
Following instruction here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPM4SwpPP4M
I was able to move Default Data Directory of PostgreSQL to another folder such as
From: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data_new
But when I move to \NAS\work\SQL, it did not work. My guess is that the problem lies in how to specify the path. I have used different ways such as
sc config postgresql-x64-16 binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin\pg_ctl.exe\" runservice -N \"postgresql-x64-16\" -D \"\\ANC\work\SQL\data" -w

sc config postgresql-x64-16 binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin\pg_ctl.exe\" runservice -N \"postgresql-x64-16\" -D \"\\\\NAS\\Work\\SQL\\data" -w 

But it did not work. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Please don't do that. The last time I checked, Windows' implementation of the CIFS protocol did not honor fsync (actually, the Windows equivalent) correctly. That means that you will end up with a corrupted database in the event of an operating system crash.
